Novel about a city of magic guilds (I don't believe it was Ravnica)
I remember reading a book back in the 2000s or 90s so it would have to be from then or earlier.
From what I can remember it was about some guy who came back to the city with a certain colored mana orb, and that city was ran by guilds for each color of mana and each had their own orb. I can't remember a whole lot about the story but I want to say he was from another guild that had been destroyed earlier and was back for revenge and to take the orbs from the other guilds.
I looked up Ravnica cause it felt like the name of it but the synopsis didnt seem right and it's newer. I wanna say im like 80% it's some kinda of Magic: The Gathering book and had to deal with planeswalker though I may be mixing it with another one up I read around the same time.
